# Convert ut8 to string

Tags: c#, utf-8

I would like to convert a Utf String  to Characters.
I have "%CE%98%CF%89%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%82+%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%81%CE%B7%CF%82" which i know it must be translated to Θωμας Κουρης.
I have tried anything. 
Help Please!

Comment: Is it an UTF-8 string? Maybe but for your _problem_ I think you're searching for the wrong term, try with **URL** encoded...

Comment: Without showing us the code that you tried we cannot help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("your+string")` could do it, but I think there might be better ways

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do URL encode decode. In that case url decode for your value is : Θωμας κουρης

This tool below helps you to encode decode urls: [Url Encode Decode](http://www.tools4geeks.com/url-encode-decode)

```
Decode: System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("value");
Encode: System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("value");
```